# Move files from sibling directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to make a batch file that moves specific files from a sibling directory using only relative paths?

E.g. `Foo/bar/executable.exe` to `Foo/quid/executable.exe` where the `bat` file is being run from `Foo/quid/bat.bat`

If so, how?

I'm primarily a C++ developer and don't know any batch, but would love to learn some. Sorry if it seems like I've put no effort into researching this first, I did but I'm struggling.

Comment: I am positive that this is not the first outing for this question. Please explain what you've tried since it was last posted and how it is more suitable here now than it was then.

Comment: This is definitely not the first time this was posted, because I commented on the previous iteration, asking how you would know which folder you were moving the files to if there was more than one sibling folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is relatively straight forward. No pun intended.  You just need to understand a few things.

1. What is your current working directory
2. A single period represents the current working directory
3. Two periods represent the directory one level up.

Here I am going to show you how this works from the command line and I am going to use the `TREE` command to show you what the current state of the folder structure looks like. The commands work the same in a batch file.

So based on your example the current working directory is the quid folder....

```
H:\foo\quid>tree H:\Foo /F /A
Folder PATH listing for volume DATA
Volume serial number is D2F3-49FA
H:\FOO
+---bar
|       file1.txt
|
\---quid
        mybatch.bat
```

We can issue a move command

```
H:\foo\quid>move ..\bar\file1.txt .
        1 file(s) moved.
```

And now your folder structure looks like this.

```
H:\foo\quid>tree H:\Foo /F /A
Folder PATH listing for volume DATA
Volume serial number is D2F3-49FA
H:\FOO
+---bar
\---quid
        file1.txt
        mybatch.bat


H:\foo\quid>
```

Comment: I see, the issue I was having was the second parameter needed to be a single period. Thank you :)